# is there a limitation for query a collection in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have watched videos about Firestore on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ). It is said that there is a limitation for a where which the max size is 1 Mb and also maximum 1 write per second.

How about the query to a collection? Is there a limitation for this? Because I will heavily rely on a parent collections to perform different queries for a lot of users. That's why I need to know the worst case scenario. I need to know if there are any limitations.

I mean something like, maximum number of query per second, max concurrent queries? Maximum number to get data from a collection in a second ? Do such limitations exis for querying a collection?

I have tried to read the documentation from [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas) and it seems there is no limitation for query in a collection. I need to make sure, maybe there is documentation that I have not read yet?

Comment: What do you mean through "limitation for query in a collection"? You are referring to the number of items you are querying in? To the number of items, your query is returning? To the number of queries that you can perform in a single collection? How about the writes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no documented limit to the number of queries you can execute against Firestore. While there is probably a physical limit, you're extremely unlikely to hit it before running into any of the documented limits (such as the 1 million concurrent users).

In other words: it is quite unlikely you'll need to worry about the read scalability or limitations of Firestore for your application. It is made to scale very well on read operations, which is precisely the reasons why it supports a more limited set of functionality, and why it has a write throughput limit on individual documents.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore scales massively for read operations.  When using the Blaze payment plan, there are no fundamental read limits like there are for write limits.  You just need to be willing to pay for all those documents reads, and the bandwidth required for all that data.  Please read the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) about billing.

Answer (score 0):

There is limit for Your reads and writes.

They have provided in their [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#free-quota) where in Free service you have limited read writes.

Each read will be counted in normal queries it acts same with writing document